# Keeping WPF GroupItems together in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to group a collection view by "region" (there will always be 5), and what I'd like to achieve is to keep all 5 GroupItems stacked vertically while only showing 7 **Groups** in my ItemsControl per row.

Example of groups, where each item has a date and 3 values, grouped by 5 regions: AS, CE, KC, NA and LAM:

[image]

The following keeps my GroupItems stacked how I want them, but since the ItemsPanel is a DockPanel, they just continue to the right for as many items as there are:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.DailyBuildPlansCollectionView, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <!-- Scrollviewer to let me scroll through the data -->
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsPresenter/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <!-- Template for each individual build plan -->
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderBrush="DarkSlateGray"
                BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid Width="127">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!-- Date across top -->
                <Border Background="AntiqueWhite"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                           Text="{Binding Day, StringFormat=MMM dd yy}"
                           Margin="2"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           FontWeight="Bold"/>

                <!-- Region along side -->
                <Border Background="AntiqueWhite"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Grid.RowSpan="2"
                           Text="{Binding Region}"
                           Margin="2"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           FontWeight="Bold"/>

                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Text="{Binding Build, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         Margin="2"
                         TextAlignment="Center"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Text="{Binding Sales}"
                           Margin="2"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Text="{Binding Inventory}"
                           Margin="2"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<!-- Group Styles - Will be grouped by region -->
<ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
```

Result:
[image]

I assumed I could get around this by changing my ItemsPanelTemplate from a DockPanel to a UniformGrid with 7 columns, but this breaks up my groups:
[image]

The end result I'd like to achieve would look like this (crossed out the dates to be less confusing, they would continue on as normal):

[image]

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: My first guess is that you should use databinding on the Grid.Column and Grid.Row value. Maybe with a mudulo on the group number or something like that...